# How to debug "python -m module_name" using pudb

Tags: python, linux, pudb

I have the following python call:

```
python -m module_name
```

The file structure is as below:

```
module_name
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
```

Previously, I debug using pudb for signle python program without `-m` in the following way:

```
python -m pudb.run file_name.py
```

Considering this, I tried the following command but got error:

```
python -m pudb.run -m module_name
```

Error messages:

```
Usage: run.py [options] SCRIPT-TO-RUN [SCRIPT-ARGUMENTS]
run.py: error: no such option: -m
```

Is there any solution for debug 'python -m module_name' using pudb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an exact solution to your problem, but if you cannot find a way to do it like that, you can instead import and start pudb in your module, for example in the __main__.py file:

```
import pudb 
pu.db

# Rest of your module code
```

And then run it with

> python -m module_name

It will automatically start in pudb that way.

Answer (score 1):

This is supported now. see this [merged PR](https://github.com/inducer/pudb/pull/390/commits)

```bash
pudb3 -m some_module
```

It also works if you use `pudb` itself as an executable module:

```bash
python -m pudb -m some_module
```